# Allowing users to script inline, what inline scripting engines are there for either .net or java?

Tags: c#, java, templates, scripting

Are there any open source scripting engines that allow you to give your users the ability to perform light scripting on pages via a web based interface?

(some objects/collections would be pre-populated, and have security in place so users can't hack into the web application's inner workings etc.)

Examples:

http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid

Also I think vBulletin has some custom scripting engine and tags where you can do things like:

```
<if: user.isloggedin>
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has the [scripting framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) (in Java 6) which would permit you (via the web) to submit a script in numerous different languages (off the top of my head, plugins are available for [Ruby](http://www.jruby.org)/[Python](http://www.jython.org)/[Javascript](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)). The scripting engine can then run this.

Pages could be modified using standard JSPs, or perhaps via [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) templates.

I'm not sure how you'd implement a meaningful form of security, though. Perhaps via spawning off a new JVM with particular access policies. That may be a little heavyweight for some scenarios, though.

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of success with [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/) as our scripting engine.

We created a graphical UI that allows a user to modify a web page.  In the background it generates a Python code and dynamically executing the code.

Comment: Yes, users are modifying existing web page.  Of course you have to do write some code to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

[Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) is awesome - fully embeddable javascript engine for .NET apps