# Are there any sandboxable scripting engines which can be integrated with PHP/Python/other?

Tags: java, php, python, mono, security

I'm performing a thought-experiment which, judging by other questions, isn't so novel after all, but I think I'll proceed anyway.  I want to sandbox a user-supplied server-side script by, among other things, confining it to a virtual filesystem and setting the root directory, and further mapping certain virtual directories to specific physical ones, inconsistent with the actual directory structure.  For example (using PHP string parsing), my preconception is "~$user/..." but the less-semantic "/$user/..." would work fine too; either might map to "users/$user/$script_name/data/...".  Yes, under certain circumstances multiple users can be affected by the script.

Since this is a thought-experiment and I therefore don't consider the implementation language an issue, I'm expecting to do it on my localhost and would rather use PHP than install something else.  (I also have Python 2 available, and could get mod_wsgi to use it instead.  I'd install Python 3 if I had to.)  Ideally, I wish a PEAR module would do this - but from what I can see none does.

I tried and failed to find a server module, such as SSJS, that could accomplish this.  The closest things to answers that I found were << [Looking for a locked down script interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095988/looking-for-a-locked-down-script-interpreter) >> and << [Allowing users to script inline, what inline scripting engines are there for either .net or java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970195/allowing-users-to-script-inline-what-inline-scripting-engines-are-there-for-eith) >>.  I'll move to Java or, less likely, Mono if I absolutely have to, but I'm not enthusiastic to the idea.  (I'm extremely rusty on Java, and have hardly used it server-side at all.  Mono is totally alien to me.)

Since they're the most promising options so far, I also wonder how extensive the sandboxing facilities are in Java and Mono.  For example, can they do virtual filesystems?  Entering APIs from Java user-code into the engine?  Are any standard APIs offered to the script, and if so can they be removed?

**Clarification**
I don't really care which way this goes, but I was actually expecting Java/Mono to be the implementation platform rather than the sandboxed one, based on the questions & answers I linked.  I'm a little surprised to see that flipped in the answers, but either way works.

Comment: There is a spidermonkey extension for [PHP (pecl)](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey) and for [Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey); not sure how much confinement they provide.

Comment: I knew I had seen the PHP one, not sure why I didn't check PECL.  Thanks!  I imagine I'd have to hack them to get them to do what I want, but at least that's something.  (You might want to make that an answer rather than just a comment.)

Comment: http://niemeyer.net/lunatic-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java sandbox (in the way implemented for browser applets) does not offer file access at all.

In general, the Java security model has only "allow or not allow" decisions for the security manager in most cases.

Of course you could design another API instead of the normal File IO api (and similar), and have your sandboxed script access then this way (and forbid the normal way by a security manager). (I suppose some of this is already implemented in the Java application engines on the market, but I do know about nothing about this).

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried to truly sandbox Mono but this might give you a starting point:

http://www.mono-project.com/MonoSandbox

File system access in the sandbox is touched on in that link.

Popular choices for [Mono scripting](http://www.mono-project.com/Scripting_With_Mono) seem to be [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) and [Python](http://ironpython.net/). Both ship with the latest version of Mono ([2.10](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10)). [Visual Basic,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/default) [Ruby](http://ironruby.net/) and [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default) (OCaml-ish) do as well.

The [Mono C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) can be easily embedded as a service for scripting. Here is a [nice article about it](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-24.html).

If you are partial to PHP, you should check out [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/).

There are many other choices. There are new .NET based scripting languages all the time. I came across [this one](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/machete-a-scripting-runtime-for) earlier today.

Comment: That looks promising!  To be honest I don't really care which language is sandboxed, so Mono could give users flexibility if my idea ever goes live.

Comment: @Jesdisciple - Glad to help. Don't be afraid to vote for answers you like.